# Can't access my own ubuntu machine on network

Tags: samba

This is a new issue. Before all machines (Linux,Mac,Windows) shared resources and were available each other. Now I can't access my own ubuntu 19.10 machine on network. The message is:

*failed to retrieve share list from server: invalid argument*

I reinstalled samba, cifs-utils, gvfs-backends multiple times but no success.

I can ping from every system. All machines belongs to the same workgroup.
Any changes in smb.conf would not make a significance difference (aka min protocol = SMB2)

netstat and nmap ports are open and listening and the firewall is inactive

Latest:
I noticed once in a while for some unknown reasons I can access my own machine, but I cannot see the other machines in the "windows network".

When I can't access my own machine every machine (including localhost) appeared dubled like below:
In this case I can see and access "windows network".

smb://localhost/
smb://localhost.local/

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
smbclient -L 192.168.0.120
Enter GATTACA\root's password: 

    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (zika server (Samba, Ubuntu))
    Backup_Zika     Disk      
Reconnecting with SMB1 for workgroup listing.
protocol negotiation failed: NT_STATUS_INVALID_NETWORK_RESPONSE
Failed to connect with SMB1 -- no workgroup available
```

139,445 ports are open if that could be relevant:

```
nmap zika
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-03-23 13:36 EDT
Nmap scan report for zika (192.168.0.120)
Host is up (0.000022s latency).
rDNS record for 192.168.0.120: zika.gattaca.net
Not shown: 994 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
23/tcp   open  telnet
80/tcp   open  http
139/tcp  open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp  open  microsoft-ds
3389/tcp open  ms-wbt-server

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.24 seconds
```

and netstat:

```
netstat -plnt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5940          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1377/teamviewerd    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      796/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1071/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      14191/cupsd         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:23              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1230/inetd          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1437/sendmail: MTA: 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      27767/smbd          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2628          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1287/dictd 1.12.1:  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      27767/smbd          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:587           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1437/sendmail: MTA: 
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1133/apache2        
tcp6       0      0 ::1:3350                :::*                    LISTEN      1075/xrdp-sesman    
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1071/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      14191/cupsd         
tcp6       0      0 :::3389                 :::*                    LISTEN      1102/xrdp           
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      27767/smbd          
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN      27767/smbd
```